# How to write proper OOP code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, html, canvas

I am playing with the HTML5 canvas element, using JS to draw some rectangles on it and then move them around, changing size and colors, etc. Currently I use mostly native JS, with jQuery for the jCanvas plugin to draw the shapes on the canvas. This is all working nicely, but I think the code could be improved.

Currently I store all rectangle properties in regular variables, like:

```
block1Height = 50;
block1Width = 50;
block1Color = '#000000';
block1X = 200;
block1Y = 100;
block2Height = 50;
block2Width = 50;
etc..
```

I am wondering whether it would be possible to just create instances of a 'block'-object. So I would have: an object called 'block', with properties 'height', 'width', 'color', etc. And then every time I create an instance of that object it has the default block properties.

The same goes for functions, I would like to do something like:

```
$block1.moveX(-100);
```

Is this possible in JS? What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a `Block` constructor function, something like this:

```
var Block = function(width, height) {
    this.width = width || 50; //50 is the default
    this.height = height || 50; //50 is the default
    this.moveX = function(x) {
        console.log("Moving by " + x);
    }
};
```

You can then create new instances of the Block "class" with the `new` operator:

```
var block1 = new Block();
block1.moveX(100); //Will print "Moving by 100"
```

The above would create a new `Block` instance with a `width` and `height` of 50 (because we didn't pass in a `width` or `height` argument). To create a bigger `Block` you could do:

```
var block2 = new Block(100, 100);
```

Note that (as stated in the comments) using `this.moveX = function` is not hugely efficient. It means every instance of `Block` has to have a copy of the `moveX` function in memory. You could improve this by adding the `moveX` method to the `prototype`:

```
Block.prototype.moveX = function(x) {
    console.log("Moving by " + x);
}
```

This way, none of the `Block` instances have a copy of the method. When you call it, the instance itself is examined but no property with the name `moveX` is found, so the `prototype` is looked at instead. There is one copy of the method shared between all instances.

Comment: @Raynos - Could you expand on that please? Why is it inefficient? What would you suggest as an alternative, `Block.prototype.moveX`?

Comment: Is it inefficient because every instance of `Block` will have to have a copy of the method in memory, whereas by declaring it as a method of the `prototype`, they all share one?

Comment: @JamesAllardice correct. One should avoid having methods as own properties when you can inherit methods from the prototype

Answer (score -2):

yes in javascript you can create json object ex:-

```
var b={
    blockheight:100,
    blockwidth:100,
    moveX:function(posx){
    //code goes here
    }
}
```